# How to insert a property into the leaf nodes of a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my data : https://api.myjson.com/bins/pmzf0

I retrieve all the leaf nodes of that data by using this function :

```
function getLeafNodes(nodes, result = []) {
    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (!nodes[i].children) {
            result.push(nodes[i]);
        } else {
            result = getLeafNodes(nodes[i].children, result);
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

This is the returned result :https://api.myjson.com/bins/12qiq4

Then I calculated the percentage info of each element by getting its max value then multiplying it by 1.2 to obtain my target Value.

```
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, leafs.map(function (o) { return o.value; }))

var targetVal = maxVal * 1.2;
```

Then I obtain my array of percentages for each element by using the following code :

```
var percentageData = leafs.map(function (o) {
    return { percentage: (o.value / targetVal * 100).toFixed(2) };
})
```

This returns an array of percentage data : https://api.myjson.com/bins/mnte4

Now how do I insert this back into my original data ?
Or is my approach wrong and I can straight away calculate the percentage info for each element in my original data without all this steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the percentage values in a separate array like,

```
var percentageData = leafs.map(function (o) {
    return { percentage: (o.value / targetVal * 100).toFixed(2) };
})
```

You can add a new percentage field to leafs using foreach like,

```
leafs.forEach(function (o) {
   o['percentage'] = (o.value / targetVal * 100).toFixed(2);
})
```

Comment: awesome. but leafs is still a separate array from my original data. How do I insert it into that?

Comment: Oh... Can you post a fiddle? That would be helpful